Non-orthogonal transformation cannot preserve standard Gaussian
Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ be multivariate standard Gaussian and $Y=f(X)$, for some diffeomorphic and unknown $f$. Given that also $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$, can we prove that $f$ must be an orthogonal transformation (i.e., multiplication of $X$ with an orthogonal matrix)? I feel like this should hold and be easy to prove.

EDIT: my initial answer below is not complete as the counterexample is not diffeomorphic.
Even in dimension one that does not hold. Take for instance
$$
f(X)=X1_{\vert X\vert\le1}+(-X)1_{\vert X\vert>1},
$$
which is obviously not linear.
If $f$ is linear though, that is $f(X)=AX$, then $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,AA^T)=\mathcal N(0,I)$, so $AA^T=I$ and $A$ is indeed orthogonal.

Your choice for $f$ is from my understanding not diffeomorphic, meaning that it must be invertible and both it and its inverse are differentiable.

Oh indeed I overlooked this condition, sorry for that, I'll edit my answer accordingly
